# Return to the first "slide" based on an event with jQuery Cycle

Tags: javascript, jquery, cycle, jquery-cycle

I'm using the [jQuery Cycle](http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/) plugin and I can find no way to return to the first slide/image via its [documentation](http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/options.html).

Is there a way to do this programmatically?  For example, say you're on slide 4, and there is a DIV with a jQuery.click() event... how would you bind that event to return you to the first slide?

Comment: Switch to [cycle2](http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle2/) may be?

Comment: Or use the `stop` command?

Comment: I can't use cycle2; I am using something else dependent on cycle. The stop command does not return to the original slide.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You did not look at the demos. Have a look at the [Goto demo](http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/goto.html):

```
$('#s1').cycle();
$('#goto1').click(function () {
    $('#s1').cycle(0);
    return false;
});
```

[**Demo here**](http://jsfiddle.net/salman/ptTgM/)

I would recommend switching to [cycle2](http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle2/) instead. You do not know what you are missing.

Comment: Thanks, precisely what I was looking for. Not sure why this isn't in the options/API and is referenced only via demo. Next time I'll look harder! And I'll look into cycle2 again but another plugin is dependent on cycle, unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

Simply use the `goto` command. As per cycle2 [documentation](http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle2/api/), this is how I would do it:

```
//"DIV with a jQuery.click() event"
<div id="go_to_slide_one" ></div>

// goto 1st slide (slides are zero indexed)
$('#go_to_slide_one').click(function() { 
    $('.cycle-slideshow').cycle('goto', 0);
});
```

Comment: Just read your comment @daveycroqet. If you cannot use cycle2 this wont work. But i'll leave my answer here in case it is of use to somebody else.